# How to stop warnings from being treated as errors in JHBuild

Tags: compiling

I tried building `mutter` module using JHBuild and it fails:

```
<snip>
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/wena/src/mutter/src'
  CC     screen.lo
core/screen.c: In function 'reload_monitor_infos':
core/screen.c:445:16: error: variable 'display' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
core/screen.c: At top level:
core/screen.c:394:1: error: 'find_monitor_with_rect' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
core/screen.c:418:1: error: 'find_main_output_for_crtc' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make[4]: *** [screen.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/wena/src/mutter/src'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wena/src/mutter/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wena/src/mutter/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wena/src/mutter'
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Error during phase build of mutter: ########## Error running make   *** [1/1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example in the question, put the following inside the "**~.jhbuildrc**" file ([reference](http://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/config-reference.html.en#config-reference-variables)):

```
module_autogenargs = {"mutter": "--disable-Werror"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `--enable-compile-warnings=yes` switch when configuring your build. That will prevent the `-Werror` compiler flag from being set during compilation.

Comment: That switch doesn't work (maybe it worked back then). What works now is `--disable-Werror`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `--disable-Werror` doesn't work, you can add the -i option (for `make`) to ignore all errors, because it looks like the developer of the program I am building physically hard-coded the `-Werror` option somewhere in his code.